# Rider 2019.1 - Launching Code Inspection from Command Line

Tags: unity-game-engine, rider, code-inspection

I am trying to run Rider IDE's code inspection flow using command line tool by referencing the following link :

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-code-inspector.html

I can not find any correct "inspection-path" as stated in the document.

This is the command syntax :

```
IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/bin/inspect.sh project-path inspection-path output-path -v2 -d subdirectory-path
```

and here is an example call :

```
IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/bin/inspect.sh ~/MyProject ~/MyProject/.idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml ~/MyProject/inspection-results-dir -v2 -d ~/MyProject/subdirectory
```

When I open ".idea" folder under my project folder, there is no "inspectionProfiles" folder and also "Project_Default.xml" file to pass as "inspection-path" parameter.

Under my project's ".idea" folder there is

```
".idea/.idea.game-unity/.idea/codeStyles/codeStyleConfig.xml"
```

When I run the following command :

```
./inspect.sh /Users/fcoskun/Projects/gameUnity/game-unity /Users/fcoskun/Projects/gameUnity/game-unity/.idea/.idea.game-unity/.idea/codeStyles/codeStyleConfig.xml /Users/fcoskun/Projects/gameUnity/game-unity -v2 -d /Users/fcoskun/Projects/gameUnity/game-unity/Assets/Scripts
```

I am getting this as result :

```
2019-07-02 12:54:34.925 rider[22432:35398688] allVms required 1.8*,1.8+
2019-07-02 12:54:34.928 rider[22432:35398694] Value of RIDER_VM_OPTIONS is (null)
2019-07-02 12:54:34.928 rider[22432:35398694] fullFileName is: /Applications/Rider.app/Contents/bin/rider.vmoptions
2019-07-02 12:54:34.928 rider[22432:35398694] fullFileName exists: /Applications/Rider.app/Contents/bin/rider.vmoptions
2019-07-02 12:54:34.928 rider[22432:35398694] Processing VMOptions file at /Applications/Rider.app/Contents/bin/rider.vmoptions
2019-07-02 12:54:34.929 rider[22432:35398694] Done



Installation home directory: file:////Applications/Rider.app/Contents
System directory: file:////Users/fcoskun/Library/Caches/Rider2019.1
Config directory: file:////Users/fcoskun/Library/Preferences/Rider2019.1
Log directory: file:////Users/fcoskun/Library/Logs/Rider2019.1

Following output will be written to a log file /Users/fcoskun/Library/Logs/Rider2019.1/frontend.log
```

In the frontend.log file, there is a NullPointerException about InspectionApplication :

```
12:54:42.572 | ERROR | InspectionApplication          | null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:430)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1682)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1631)
    at com.jetbrains.rider.projectView.SolutionManager.openDirectoryInteractive(SolutionManager.kt:141)
    at com.jetbrains.rider.projectView.SolutionManager.openDirectoryInteractive$default(SolutionManager.kt:131)
    at com.jetbrains.rider.projectView.ideaInterop.RiderProjectOpenProcessor.a(RiderProjectOpenProcessor.kt:44)
    at com.jetbrains.rider.projectView.ideaInterop.RiderProjectOpenProcessor.doOpenProject(RiderProjectOpenProcessor.kt:37)
....
....
```

Is there anyone who can help me on this? How should I call that inspect.sh script?

Answer (score 1):

I think Re# CLT should be used instead. https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/command-line.html